# Filter /var/log/messages file data from target machine by date & time

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am using below python script to filter data from /var/log/messages file of target machine by date & time .
But getting syntax error

I am using python version 2.7 & will not be able to upgrade python version

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb
import os

from subprocess import PIPE, Popen


def cmdline(command):
    process = Popen(
        args=command,
        stdout=PIPE,
        shell=True
    )
    return process.communicate()[0]

out4=cmdline('sshpass -p redhat  ssh  -o ConnectTimeout=6  -o  NumberOfPasswordPrompts=2 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -tt ricky@192.168.0.50 "echo redhat | sudo -S zless /var/log/messages* | grep \'^Sep  9\' | awk  \' \$3 > "09:30" && \$3 < "23:50" \'  "')

print(out4)
```

Getting below output while executing this script

```
Connection to 192.168.0.50 closed.
awk:  $3 > 09:30 && $3 < 23:50
awk:         ^ syntax error
awk:  $3 > 09:30 && $3 < 23:50
awk:                       ^ syntax error
[sudo] password for ricky:
```

Anyone please help me to correct it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are falling into quote hell due to multiple levels of special char handling, by the multiple shells you're running one inside the other.

You can reduce your doom, by avoiding using `shell=True` so it is one less shell to escape for:

```
p = subprocess.run([
    'sshpass', '-p', 'redhat' 
     'ssh',
     '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=6',
     '-o', 'NumberOfPasswordPrompts=2',
     '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no',
     '-tt', 'ricky@192.168.0.50'
     """sudo -S zless /var/log/messages* | grep '^Sep  9' | awk  ' \$3 > "09:30" && \$3 < "23:50" '"""
], input='redhat\n', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out4 = p.stdout
```

Comment: Hi nosklo,
Thanks for your update
getting below error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hello_get.py", line 19, in <module>
    p = subprocess.run([
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'

Comment: `subprocess.run` was added on python 3.5 @SatwikMukherjee update your python

Comment: any possiblity in Python 2.7.5 by doing any modification my using existing module ?

Comment: But... 2.7.5 was released 5 years ago!! There's no reason to be still using it @SatwikMukherjee - I believe you can rewrite it to use `Popen` instead: `p = subprocess.Popen([...], stdin='redhat\n', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` then `out4 = p.communicate()[0]`

Comment: getting bellow error

    """sudo -S zless /var/log/messages* | grep '^Sep  9' | awk  ' \$3 > "09:30" && \$3 < "23:50" '"""], stdin='redhat\n', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 703, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1105, in _get_handles
    p2cread = stdin.fileno()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen([...], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` then `out4 = p.communicate('redhat\n')[0]`

Comment: one more thing I want to use all the values as variable like below

 p = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', 'redhat',
                'ssh',
                '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=6',
                '-o', 'NumberOfPasswordPrompts=2',
                '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no',
                '-tt', 'ricky@192.168.0.50',
                """sudo -S zless $log | grep '^${month_start:0:3}  $day_start' | awk  ' $3 >= "$str_time" && $3 <= "$end_time" '"""], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

Comment: Where variable are taken as below

where variables are below

ip  = form.getvalue('ip')
month_start  = form.getvalue('month_start')
day_start =form.getvalue('day_start')
str_time  = form.getvalue('str_time')
log = form.getvalue('log')

end_time  = form.getvalue('end_time')
log = form.getvalue('log')

day_start1=int(day_start)
day_end1=int(day_end)


os.environ["ip"] = ip

os.environ["month_start"] = month_start
os.environ["day_start"] = day_start
os.environ["str_time"] = str_time

os.environ["end_time"] = end_time
os.environ["log"] = log
os.environ["passwd"] = passwd

Comment: @SatwikMukherjee use normal text formatting in the command string, like this: `"""sudo -S zless {log}| grep '^{month_start} {day_start}' | awk ' $3 >= "{str_time}" && $3 <= "{end_time}" '""".format(log=form.getvalue('log'), month_start=form.getvalue('month_start')[:3], day_start=form.getvalue('day_start'), str_time=form.getvalue('str_time'), end_time=form.getvalue('end_time'))`

Comment: Remember that it means anyone with access to that form can run anything as administrator in the remote machine. Huge security hole, you'd have to validate every variable to make sure it doesn't contain commands.

Comment: getting one issue , time order is not correct in output as original 
Original
---------
Sep  9 12:03:35 
Sep  9 12:03:37 
Sep  9 13:00:01
Sep  9 13:01:01 
Sep  9 14:00:01
Sep  9 15:00:01
Sep  9 16:01:02

Output getting
---------------------
Sep 9 13:15:04  
Sep 9 13:15:04 
Sep 9 14:00:01  
Sep 9 14:01:01 
Sep 9 16:50:02 
Sep 9 17:00:01
Sep 9 12:03:35 
Sep 9 12:50:01 
Sep 9 13:00:01